# VS 2012 addin - manually installing dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook, installshield

I just upgraded (if you can call it an upgrade) from VS 2010 to VS 2012. They are now forcing you to use installshield Essentials, which is rubbish and you need to sacrifice a chicken, whilst performing satanic rituals to get it to work.

So my question, can I install the ADDIN manually? I know what registry entries are needed. I ask because I want to know if I can build the addin and then get a third party installer and use that.

Also the MS addins seem to use VSTO, can I not use a simple DLL? I ask because I see my NOD32 antivirus addin is a simple DLL.

Comment: No one is "forcing" you to use anything.  They just took away a garbage project type and suggested one possible alternative. FWIW, it's not even named "Essentials"  it's named "Limited Edition".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is enough to include in the installer the DLL, VSTO manifest file and create the registry entries as documented. This way you can create the installer with any tool that integrates in VS, like [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html)(disclaimer: I work on its development). They are both free for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you don't have to use VSTO at all. On the low level, your COM addin is just an in-proc COM server (dll). The COM object exposed by the add-0in must implement the IDTExtensibility2 interface. That's it, there are no other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

See: [VSTO 4 ( 2010 ) Lessons Learned](http://blog.iswix.com/2010/10/vsto-4-2010-lessons-learned.html)

FWIW, I've authored about 10 VSTO AddIn installers and half of them using InstallShield Limited Edition.  It actually works really well once you fully understand the deployment requirements and how to use the tools.  The primary problem with ISLE is that it does hide a lot of the functionality that's in Windows Installer and more fully explosed by InstallShield Professional Edition.

ISLE allows you to consume setup prerequisites (.PRQ files) but doesn't provide an editor to tweak them if needed.  Using an eval version of InstallShield and then back porting the changes to ISLE works nicely there.    Also the use of Windows Installer XML (WiX) to create merge modules that get consumed by ISLE solves most of the other problems.

I've got this type of installer template down to the point of taking < 8 hours per project including 
project management, testing and close out.  Someone brand new to installers should expect to take several months to get something that "seems" to work.